# rust: Define a generic function that will accept a borrow to any iterable of things that implement a certain trait

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I have a trait and a thing that implements that trait:

```
trait HasPosition2D {
    fn x(&self) -> &i32;
    fn y(&self) -> &i32;
    fn x_mut(&mut self) -> &mut i32;
    fn y_mut(&mut self) -> &mut i32;
}

impl HasPosition2D for (i32,i32) {
    fn x(&self) -> &i32 {&self.0}
    fn y(&self) -> &i32 {&self.1}
    fn x_mut(&mut self) -> &mut i32 {&mut self.0}
    fn y_mut(&mut self) -> &mut i32 {&mut self.1}
}
```

I can now define generic functions that accept anything that implements HasPosition2D. e.g

```
fn print(p: &impl HasPosition2D) {
    println!("{} {}", p.x(), p.y());
}
```

I have also defined a function that accepts anything that can be turned into an iterable of HasPosition2D. i.e

```
fn print_all(ps: impl IntoIterator<Item=impl HasPosition2D>) {
    for p in ps {
        println!("{} {}", p.x(), p.y());
    }
}
```

This allows me to swap the container type without having to change the code. e.g

```
let ps = vec![(42,42), (42,42)];
print_all(ps);
let ps = [(42,42), (42,42)];
print_all(ps);
```

However, the above function moves the container, I would instead like to borrow. e.g

```
//does not complile
fn print_all2(ps: &impl IntoIterator<Item=impl HasPosition2D>) {
    for p in ps {
        println!("{} {}", p.x(), p.y());
    }
}
```

But this gives the error:

```
error[E0277]: `&impl IntoIterator<Item = impl HasPosition2D>` is not an iterator
  --> src\main.rs:35:14
   |
35 |     for p in ps {
   |              ^^ `&impl IntoIterator<Item = impl HasPosition2D>` is not an iterator
   |
   = help: the trait `Iterator` is not implemented for `&impl IntoIterator<Item = impl HasPosition2D>`
   = help: the trait `Iterator` is implemented for `&mut I`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `IntoIterator` for `&impl IntoIterator<Item = impl HasPosition2D>`
```

I would also like to define a similar function that accepts a mutable borrow.

And finally, how could I create a type alias for each of these impl traits? ( using `#![feature(type_alias_impl_trait)]` and/or `#![feature(trait_alias)]` )

e.g, for the non borrowed version:

```
type HasPosition2DList = impl IntoIterator<Item=impl HasPosition2D>;
```

or

```
//does not compile
trait HasPosition2DList = IntoIterator<Item=impl HasPosition2D>;
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`into_iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/index.html#iterating-by-reference) takes `self` by value (not reference), so if you are wanting to avoid a move, then that won't fix your problem. `Vec` can [`deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-Deref) into a slice, so I think you want something more like this, in order to accept either type as a paramter:

```rust
fn print_all(ps: &[impl HasPosition2D]) {
    for p in ps {
        println!("{} {}", p.x(), p.y());
    }
}
```

You can then call it as you showed in your example, just adding `&` to borrow:

```rust
fn main() {
    let ps = vec![(42,42), (42,42)];
    print_all(&ps);

    let ps = [(42,42), (42,42)];
    print_all(&ps);
}
```

Comment: You are correct, a slice is more what I am after. Thankyou.

Comment: No problem! If you wrap your tuple in a struct, you can get even more flexibility about where it can be used by using the `From` (and `Into`) traits, and structs are also easier (IMO) to work with than traits.